# Wildcat trail when Valley Drive is closed

Tags: usa, hiking, utah, arizona

I am planning a trip to Monument Valley in March. At this period, Valley Drive is closed at 4:30 pm. Is it still possible to hike Wild Cat trail after that time, from "The View" parking lot?

Comment: I think this question belongs on [Outdoors.SE].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally dropped and email to The View hotel (inside Monument Valley).

> The wildcat trail hike must be completed before the sun goes down.  As
>   long as you do that you can stay on it later than 4:30.

Comment: There is nothing to stop you from hicking after sundown (been there).